# What does WolframAlpha do here?

Tags: calculus

i'm trying to understand, how WolframAlpha solves an quite difficult Integral, however i don't know what wolframAlpha is doing in this step:

```
1 / ((p-1) * p) --> ((1/(p-1)) - (1/p))
```

Everything i could think of is --> ((1/(p-1)) * (1/p))

[image]

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: As it says in your picture, they use partial fractions (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction) to split $\frac{1}{(p-1)p}$ into $\frac{1}{p-1} - \frac{1}{p}$

Comment: I'm unreasonably bothered by the fact that the alt-text is captured in that image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is performing the partial fraction decomposition. You can check that result is correct by recombining fractions like so:
$$\frac{1}{p-1} - \frac{1}{p} = 
   \frac{p}{p (p-1)} - \frac{p-1}{p(p-1)} = \frac{p -(p-1)}{p (p-1)} = \frac{1}{p(p-1)}$$
*(credit-waived; above is a verbatim copy of another user's now deleted answer).*